# getSelectedRow method keep returning row 0

Tags: swing

I try to select a row from jTable and store the value into topicId. Here are my codes.

```
    jTable.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
            if (jTable.getSelectedRow() >= 0 && jTable.getValueAt(jTable.getSelectedRow(), 0) != null) {
                    topicId = (Integer)jTable.getValueAt(jTable.getSelectedRow(), 0);}

            System.out.println(topicId);
                eForumTopics topics = new eForumTopics(topicId);
                topics.retrieveThread();
                getJFrame().dispose();
                eForumThreadContent myWindow = new eForumThreadContent(topicId);
                myWindow.getJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here are my codes for scroll pane.

```
    private JScrollPane getJScrollPane() {
    if (jScrollPane == null) {
        jScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        jScrollPane.setBounds(new Rectangle(75, 220, 800, 450));
        jScrollPane.setViewportView(getJTable());
    }
    return jScrollPane;
}
```

And here are the codes for jTable.

```
    private JTable getJTable() {
    if (jTable == null) {
        Vector columnNames = new Vector(); // Vector class allows dynamic
                                            // array of objects
        Vector data = new Vector();
        try {
            DBController db = new DBController();
            db.setUp("IT Innovation Project");
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance();
            String dsn = "IT Innovation Project";
            String s = "jdbc:odbc:" + dsn;
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(s, "", "");
            String sql = "Select topic_title,topic_description,topic_by from forumTopics WHERE topic_category = '"+category+"'";
            java.sql.Statement statement = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
            int columns = metaData.getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                columnNames.addElement(metaData.getColumnName(i));
            }
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                Vector row = new Vector(columns);
                for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                    row.addElement(resultSet.getObject(i)); 
                }
                data.addElement(row);
            }
            resultSet.close();
            ((Connection) statement).close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        jTable = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        TableColumn column;
        for (int i = 0; i < jTable.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            column = jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            if (i == 1) {
                column.setPreferredWidth(400); // second column is bigger
            }else {
                column.setPreferredWidth(200);
            }
        }
        String header[] = { "Title", "Description", "Posted by" };

        for (int i = 0; i < jTable.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            TableColumn column1 = jTable.getTableHeader().getColumnModel()
                    .getColumn(i);

            column1.setHeaderValue(header[i]);
        }
        jTable.getTableHeader().setFont( new Font( "Dialog" , Font.PLAIN, 20 ));
        jTable.getTableHeader().setForeground(Color.white);
        jTable.getTableHeader().setBackground(new Color(102, 102, 102));
        jTable.setEnabled(false);
        jTable.setRowHeight(100);
        jTable.getRowHeight();
        jTable.setFont( new Font( "Dialog" , Font.PLAIN, 18 ));
        jTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
```

I not sure whether is my table or scroll pane got problem. Whenever I selected any rows in the jTable, for example, 4 or 5 or 6, the result keep returning me row 0. Somebody can help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: unrelated: don't do any manual sizing/positioning (like f.i. setBounds), that's the exclusive task of a layoutManager

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no point in adding a mouse listener to store the selected row in a field. The table knows its selected row(s), and moreover, the selection can change without using the mouse.

If you want to do something (like loading details of a selected row) each time the selection changes, then add a selection listener:

```
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            int viewRow = table.getSelectedRow();
            if (viewRow >= 0) {
                int modelRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel();
                Integer topicId = tableModel.getTopicIdAtRow(modelRow);
                // todo load the details for topicId
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there any other ways that I can stick with the codes which I posted? As in even I move the selected rows method out of the mouse listener, it still does not work. I am still new to this field so your codes seem quite high standard for me.

Comment: I don't understand your question. A mouse listener is used to detect mouse clicks. You want to detect changes in the selection of a JTable, so a mouse listener is not the appropriate tool. If you don't understand what my code does and why it does it that way, then start by reading the javadoc of the methods used, and if you still don't understand, then ask me. But continuing to use the bad tool for the job won't lead you anywhere.

Comment: So how do I link to another page by clicking on certain row? Because from your codes right, I cannot click on the table.

Comment: Then a mouse listener could be the answer. Or a button next to the table, which opens the selected row.